# How to delete from an UbuntuListView?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm trying to learn how to use an `UbuntuListView`. Items will be added at runtime, but for demo I just hardcoded them.

What I need is a way of removing existing list items. Here's my code and a screenshot.

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Ubuntu.Components 1.2

MainView {

    width: units.gu(40)
    height: units.gu(30)

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {itemName: "one"}
        ListElement {itemName: "two"}
        ListElement {itemName: "three"}
    }

    UbuntuListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel

        delegate: ListItem {
            id: listItem
            Label {
                text: itemName
            }
            leadingActions: ListItemActions {
                actions: [
                    Action {
                        iconName: "delete"
                        onTriggered: listItem.destroy()
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I drag the second list item and slide it to the right. The delete option appears, but when I click it, I get the following error:

```
Main.qml:29: Error: Invalid attempt to destroy() an indestructible object
```

I followed the examples from the [API docs](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04/Ubuntu.Components.ListItem/).

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I also need to remove the corresponding model item, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> By the way, I also need to remove the corresponding model item, but how do I do that?

Apparently this was the solution: I just deleted from the model, and the view updated itself.

- I added an ID to the listElements:

  ```
  ListElement {itemId: 1; itemName: "one"}
  ```
- In the action's `onTriggered`, I searched for the item and removed it from the model:

  ```
  onTriggered: {
      for(var i = 0; i < listModel.count; i++) {
          if(listModel.get(i).itemId === itemId) {
              listModel.remove(i);
              break;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Actually, searching is not even necessary. According to the API docs for `QtQuick.ListView`:

> The index is exposed as an accessible `index` property.

So it's possible to write just:

```
onTriggered: {
    listModel.remove(index);
}
```

So I suppose the object was indestructible because it still had a corresponding item in the model - which makes perfect sense. But in this case... maybe the documentation is a bit misleading.